# Removing a factor from ggplot color legend when multiple are specified

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am mapping two factors to the `color` argument in ggplot and want to remove one from the legend.

I have these data.

```
Data <- structure(list(StudyArea = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", 
"CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), Obs = c(190L, 481L, 219L, 190L, 
481L, 219L, 190L, 481L, 219L), InSituPred = c(180, 462, 199, 
180, 462, 199, 180, 462, 199), InSituSE = c(9.57382456553708, 
16.5306359391421, 9.51070020039693, 9.57382456553708, 16.5306359391421, 
9.51070020039693, 9.57382456553708, 16.5306359391421, 9.51070020039693
), variable = c("ExSituAAA", "ExSituAAA", "ExSituAAA", "ExSituBBB", 
"ExSituBBB", "ExSituBBB", "ExSituCCC", "ExSituCCC", "ExSituCCC"
), value = c(NA, 500, 172, 156, NA, 161, 200, 562, NA), SE = c(20.8552264204181, 
16.1382421185167, 21.43693858142, 20.8552264204181, 16.1382421185167, 
21.43693858142, 20.8552264204181, 16.1382421185167, 21.43693858142
)), .Names = c("StudyArea", "Obs", "InSituPred", "InSituSE", 
"variable", "value", "SE"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

And using the code below, can make the plot below.

```
ggplot(Data)+
  geom_point(aes(x=StudyArea, y=value, color=variable),size=3, shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=StudyArea, ymin=value-SE, ymax=value+SE, color=variable),lty = 2, cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(x=StudyArea, y=InSituPred, color=StudyArea),size=3, shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=StudyArea, ymin=InSituPred-InSituSE, ymax=InSituPred+InSituSE, color=StudyArea),lty=1,cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(x=StudyArea, y=Obs, color=StudyArea),shape="*",size=12)
```

[image: Fig]

I want to remove the StudyArea colors from the legend (AAA:CCC) so that it only contains ExSituAAA, ExSituBBB, ExSituCCC.

**ADDITION**
Using the code below (with the helpful comments from @shadow) I can create the figure below.

```
p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x=StudyArea))+
  geom_point(aes(y=value, color=variable),size=3, shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-SE, ymax=value+SE, color=variable),lty = 2, cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(y=InSituPred, color=StudyArea),size=3, shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=InSituPred-InSituSE, ymax=InSituPred+InSituSE, color=StudyArea),lty=1,cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(y=Obs, color=StudyArea),shape="*",size=12) +
  scale_color_discrete(breaks=c("ExSituAAA", "ExSituBBB", "ExSituCCC"))

p +  scale_color_manual(name="Study Area \nPrediction", 
                        values=c("red", "blue", "darkgreen","red","blue","darkgreen"), 
                        breaks=c("ExSituAAA", "ExSituBBB", "ExSituCCC"))
```

[image: FigureII]

I want to add a `linetype` to the legend specifying a solid line = InSitu and a dotted line = ExSitu.

I specified the `linetype` manually (and not through a factor in `aes`) using `lty` because I needed to also specify `color` .  Looking at the `head` below, the Data$SE is `lty` = 2, and the Data$InSituSE is `lty` 1.

>

```
 head(Data)
  StudyArea Obs InSituPred  InSituSE  variable value       SE
1       AAA 190        180  9.573825 ExSituAAA    NA 20.85523
2       BBB 481        462 16.530636 ExSituAAA   500 16.13824
3       CCC 219        199  9.510700 ExSituAAA   172 21.43694
4       AAA 190        180  9.573825 ExSituBBB   156 20.85523
5       BBB 481        462 16.530636 ExSituBBB    NA 16.13824
6       CCC 219        199  9.510700 ExSituBBB   161 21.43694
```

Thus, any suggestions on how to add a `linetype` legend with a solid line = InSitu and a dotted line = ExSitu would be appreciated.

Example: I want to add...

[image: figIII]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question and perhaps a matter of taste, anyway, here's a thought: to me it seems slightly redundant to map study area _both_ to x and colour. Perhaps an idea would be to use colour only to differentiate between In- and Ex-situ?

Comment: @Henrik, I need to have the `color` of the `InSituPred` and `Obs` match the `StudyArea.`  In addition, I wanted to have the `variable` `color` match that of `StudyArea.`  I have added a few more additions to the questions that provide more specifics and build from the comments of @shadow.  thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `?scale_color_discrete` to specify the breaks. In your case this could be something like the following:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=StudyArea))+
  geom_point(aes(y=value, color=variable),size=3, shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-SE, ymax=value+SE, color=variable),lty = 2, cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(y=InSituPred, color=StudyArea),size=3, shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=InSituPred-InSituSE, ymax=InSituPred+InSituSE, color=StudyArea),lty=1,cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(y=Obs, color=StudyArea),shape="*",size=12) +
  scale_color_discrete(breaks=c("ExSituAAA", "ExSituBBB", "ExSituCCC"))
```

EDIT: Yes, it is possible to specify the colors. Since I don't really understand what coloring scheme you want, here are some examples (not all are meant entirely seriously).

```
p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x=StudyArea))+
  geom_point(aes(y=value, color=variable),size=3, shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-SE, ymax=value+SE, color=variable),lty = 2, cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(y=InSituPred, color=StudyArea),size=3, shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=InSituPred-InSituSE, ymax=InSituPred+InSituSE, color=StudyArea),lty=1,cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(y=Obs, color=StudyArea),shape="*",size=12) 
p +  scale_color_manual(name="Study Area \nPrediction", 
                        values=c("red", "blue", "darkgreen","red","blue","darkgreen"), 
                        breaks=c("ExSituAAA", "ExSituBBB", "ExSituCCC"))
p +  scale_color_manual(name="Study Area \nPrediction", 
                        values=c("black", "black", "black", "red","blue","darkgreen"), 
                        breaks=c("ExSituAAA", "ExSituBBB", "ExSituCCC"))
p +  scale_color_manual(name="Study Area \nPrediction", 
                        values=c("white", "yellow", "pink", "red","blue","darkgreen"), 
                        breaks=c("ExSituAAA", "ExSituBBB", "ExSituCCC"))
```

ADDITION: This would be much easier, if you clean and restructure your data before plotting. Here's my attampt:

```
df <- with(Data, data.frame(area=rep(StudyArea, 2),
                            exarea=c(variable,rep(variable[c(1,4,7)], 3)),
                            value=c(value, InSituPred), 
                            se=c(SE, InSituSE), 
                            obs = rep(Obs, 2),
                            situ=rep(c("in", "ex"), each=nrow(Data))))
df <- df[!duplicated(df),]
```

Then the plotting becomes much easier:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=area))+
  geom_point(aes(y=value, color=exarea),size=3, shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se, color=exarea, lty=situ), cex=0.75)+                   
  geom_point(aes(y=obs, color=exarea),shape="*",size=12) 

p +  scale_color_manual(name="Study Area \nPrediction", 
                    values=c("red", "blue", "darkgreen"), 
                    breaks=c("ExSituAAA", "ExSituBBB", "ExSituCCC")) +
   scale_linetype_manual(name="Situ", 
                         values=c(1,2), 
                         breaks=c("in", "ex"), 
                         labels=c("InSitu", "ExSitu"))
```

EDIT2: It is possible to use the original data for this. You have to put the `lty` inside the `aes`-function and then use `scale_linetype_manual` as before. Here it goes:

```
p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x=StudyArea))+
  geom_point(aes(y=value, color=variable),size=3, shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-SE, ymax=value+SE, color=variable, lty="2"), cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(y=InSituPred, color=StudyArea),size=3, shape=1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=InSituPred-InSituSE, ymax=InSituPred+InSituSE, color=StudyArea, lty="1"),cex=0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(y=Obs, color=StudyArea),shape="*",size=12) 
p +  scale_color_manual(name="Study Area \nPrediction", 
                        values=c("red", "blue", "darkgreen","red","blue","darkgreen"), 
                        breaks=c("ExSituAAA", "ExSituBBB", "ExSituCCC")) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(name="Situ", 
                        values=c(1,2), 
                        breaks=c("1", "2"), 
                        labels=c("InSitu", "ExSitu"))
```

It really is usually better practice to restructure the data instead. If you want to make any more changes to this code, it will be very hard to do. The code is already rather difficult to read. So if it is at all possible to restructer your dataset (it usually is) then consider taking the approach mentioned above.

Comment: @shodow, thanks for the answer.  Once I use scale_color_discrete() is it also possible to specify the colors used?  I want EsSituAAA:ExSituBBB to be `c("red","blue","darkgreen")`.  However, simply adding the code below results in an error as there are two specifications for color.   `scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue","darkgreen"),labs(fill="StudyArea\n Prediction"))`

Comment: I have added an **ADDITION** above, but can also open a new question...  Thanks for your continued helps!

Comment: Thanks!  Your restructure is very helpful.  For application to another data set that I have however, manual addition of `linetype` is a bit more straight forward.  Is it possible to add the `linetype` manually as in the example above?